# Show/Hide div on each link click - how to optimize the code?

Tags: jquery, optimization

I have created code to show/hide multiple `<div>` elements when clicking on text. When you click on text at the top, it shows the associated `<div>` below and hides the others.

How can I optimize this with fewer lines of code?

```js
//-- flag section
$('.contact-div #uk').click(function() {
  $('.contact-div .china').hide();
  $('.contact-div .uk').show();
  $('.contact-div .india').hide();
  $('.contact-div .malta').hide();

  //-- flag images
  $('#uk').addClass('scaleimg');
  $('#china').removeClass('scaleimg');
  $('#india').removeClass('scaleimg');
  $('#malta').removeClass('scaleimg');
});

$('.contact-div #china').click(function() {
  $('.contact-div .china').show();
  $('.contact-div .uk').hide();
  $('.contact-div .india').hide();
  $('.contact-div .malta').hide();

  //-- flag images
  $('#uk').removeClass('scaleimg');
  $('#china').addClass('scaleimg');
  $('#india').removeClass('scaleimg');
  $('#malta').removeClass('scaleimg');
});

$('.contact-div #india').click(function() {
  $('.contact-div .china').hide();
  $('.contact-div .uk').hide();
  $('.contact-div .india').show();
  $('.contact-div .malta').hide();

  //-- flag images
  $('#uk').removeClass('scaleimg');
  $('#china').removeClass('scaleimg');
  $('#india').addClass('scaleimg');
  $('#malta').removeClass('scaleimg');
});

$('.contact-div #malta').click(function() {
  $('.contact-div .china').hide();
  $('.contact-div .uk').hide();
  $('.contact-div .india').hide();
  $('.contact-div .malta').show();

  //-- flag images
  $('#uk').removeClass('scaleimg');
  $('#china').removeClass('scaleimg');
  $('#india').removeClass('scaleimg');
  $('#malta').addClass('scaleimg');

});
```

```css
.contact-div {
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.contact-div .flag {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.contact-div .flag span {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.cont-address {
  margin-left: 23px;
}
.cont-address ul li {
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.cont-address ul li i:before {
  margin: 15px 0 0 -20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.china,
.india,
.malta {
  display: none;
}
.scaleimg img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.19);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.19);
  -o-transform: scale(1.19);
  transform: scale(1.19);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-div">
  <div class="flag">
    <span id="uk" class="scaleimg">UK</span>
    <span id="china">China</span>
    <span id="india">India</span>
    <span id="malta">Malta</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cont-address">
    <ul class="uk">
      <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> UK,
        <br>Address of UK
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="china">
      <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> China,
        <br>Address of China
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="india">
      <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> India
        <br>Address of India</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="malta">
      <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Malta,
        <br>Address of Malta</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

View on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/x45gqmmu/)

Comment: Please post your code (eventhough it is viewable in the jsfiddle)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x45gqmmu/16/ check this out

Comment: @HassanALi That is still not really good. Take a look at the other answers around here. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

https://jsfiddle.net/x45gqmmu/15/

```
$('.contact-div .flag > span').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");

  $('.contact-div .cont-address > ul').hide();
  $('.contact-div .' + id).show();

  $(".scaleimg").removeClass("scaleimg");
  $('#' + id).addClass('scaleimg');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try [this(fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x45gqmmu/2/)

```
$('.flag span').click(function(){
    $('.cont-address ul').hide();
    $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).show();
})
```

Comment: have in mind, that this works for showed html structure

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is based on:

- [:not  selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```js
$(function () {
  $('.contact-div .flag span').click(function() {
    $('.contact-div ul:not(.' + this.id + ')').hide();
    $('.contact-div ul.' + this.id).show();

    $('div.flag span').toggleClass('scaleimg')
  });
});
```

```css
.contact-div{float: left; margin:16px 0 0; padding: 0;}
.contact-div .flag{margin: 0 0 10px;}
.contact-div .flag span{margin-left: 5px;}
.cont-address{margin-left: 23px;}
.cont-address ul li{line-height: 24px; color: #000000; margin-bottom: 15px;}
.cont-address ul li i:before{margin:15px 0 0 -20px; font-size: 20px;}

.china, .india, .malta{display:none;}
.scaleimg img{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.19);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.19);
  -o-transform: scale(1.19);
  transform: scale(1.19);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="contact-div">
    <div class="flag">
        <span id="uk" class="scaleimg">UK</span>
        <span id="china">China</span>
        <span id="india">India</span>
        <span id="malta">Malta</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-address">
        <ul class="uk">
            <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> UK, <br>
                Address of UK
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="china">
            <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> China, <br>
                Address of China
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="india">
            <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> India <br>
                Address of India</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="malta">
            <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Malta, <br>
                Address of Malta</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a single JavaScript event listener with some changes to the attributes in your HTML (although, it could also be accomplished without doing so) and the editing of one of your CSS rules, highlighted below:

```js
var current=document.querySelector(".cont-address>.show"),
    flags=document.querySelector(".flag"),
    country;
flags.addEventListener("click",function(evt){
    var target=event.target;
    if(country=target.dataset.country)
        if(country=document.getElementById(country)){
            current.classList.remove("show");
            country.classList.add("show");
            current=country;
        }
},0);
```

```css
.contact-div{
    float:left;
    margin:16px 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
.contact-div>.flag{
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
.contact-div>.flag>span {
    margin-left:5px;
}
.cont-address{
    margin-left:23px;
}
.cont-address>ul:not(.show){/* changed selector from ".china,.india,.malta" */
    display:none;
}
.cont-address>ul>li{
    line-height:24px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-div">
    <div class="flag">
        <span data-country="uk">UK</span>
        <span data-country="china">China</span>
        <span data-country="india">India</span>
        <span data-country="malta">Malta</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-address">
        <ul class="show" id="uk"><li>UK,<br>Address of UK</li></ul>
        <ul id="china"><li>China,<br>Address of China</li></ul>
        <ul id="india"><li>India,<br>Address of India</li></ul>
        <ul id="malta"><li>Malta,<br>Address of Malta</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```